# get_post_meta bringing back results, but $wpdb->postmeta doesn't

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, meta-query

I'm trying to discover if post exists, based on `post_title` & metadata `post_language`.
Until now, the best way I discovered, was using methods appearing in posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421169/how-to-join-postmeta-table-and-get-the-posts-before-the-date-of-custom-field-usi), [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/check-if-post-title-exists-insert-post-if-doesnt-add-incremental-to-meta-if), or [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350624/prepare-wpdb-with-meta-key-and-meta-value).

Thing is this, that when I am calling directly `get_post_meta` method, I get the meta property value I was looking for

```
get_post_meta($post_exists_id, 'post_lang')[0] //returns "en" as expected
```

Furthermore, when I run my custom `post_exists` method, it will return me an ID.

```
function especialidades_post_exists( $title ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
        WHERE 1=1
        AND (p.post_title = %s)
        AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
    ";
    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( $query, $title ) 
    );
}
```

But if I will add a postmeta lookup into the method, it will fail, It will not find the postmeta property, and the query will return 0.

```
function especialidades_post_exists( $title, $language ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
        WHERE 1=1
        AND (p.post_title = %s)
        AND (pm.post_lang = %s)
        AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
    ";
    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( $query, $title, $language ) 
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? The postmeta property is there (as I showed before by running `get_post_meta`), so how come it does not find it?

I also have tried to apply this code, but still, it doesn't return me the desired result.

```
$another_query_args = array(
   'name' => $item_name,
   'post_type' => 'especialidades',
   'meta_query'    => array (
      array (
         'key'     => 'post_lang',
         'value'   => $language,
         'compare' => '='
      )
   ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $another_query_args );
```

The problem is that I got 3 languages: PT, ES & EN.
It's always returning me the first result (PT), even though I have 3 posts pf the 3 languages. I wish to check only if post of specific language exists.

If someone will be able to share me some light, on what's wrong in my method, I'll appreciate it a lot!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL query is invalid regarding the WP database structure.

`wp_postmeta` table has two columns that will help you here.
`meta_key` : the name of your meta (`post_lang` in your case)
`meta_value` : the value of your meta (`en`, `es`, ...)

Your SQL query should look like this instead.
What changed is that you need to query the `wp_postmeta.meta_key` column to match your meta name and `wp_postmeta.meta_value` to match your language.

```sql
SELECT p.ID
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
WHERE 1=1
AND (p.post_title = %s)
AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
AND (pm.meta_key = 'post_lang')
AND (pm.meta_value = %s)
```

You could also add the `JOIN` condition to retrieve only the rows that you need.

```sql
SELECT p.ID
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON (p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'post_lang' AND pm.meta_value = %s)
WHERE 1=1
AND (p.post_title = %s)
AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
```

You can try to run this query in your database management tool to see how it works. You can also add a more "human friendly" `SELECT` clause to better understand the links between the tables.

```sql
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value
```

Comment: Thank you, man!!!!! You saved me tons of time and continuing frustration, lol :)